# How do I implement the protocols for the Three20 framework?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, sdk, uiimage, three20

I've been trying to implement the Three20 framework in my iPhone SDK app.

I'm a bit confused as to implementing the proper methods. Is there any guide as to what to implement in order to make the TTPhotoViewController work? I know how to implement protocols, but the code is very difficult to read.

Anyone know any guides with this specific framework or have any experience with this and can explain what I need to implement specifically? (because my app is crashing probably because I haven't implemented all the needed methods)

Comment: [OT] Do apple actually allow projects using Three20 into the App Store now?
I remember there was an issue for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search three20's source files for the declaration of the missing protocol. You'll find a header file that shows exactly what methods you need. Copy paste them into your code and implement away!

Comment: How do I implement the properties?